# Using alias in the middle of bash command

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Is it possible to substitute an alias in the middle of the command. for e.g.  If suppose I have an alias

```
alias get_pods= 'kubectl get pods -n mynamespace'
```

This works perfectly fine when I do "get_pods" from bash command line.

As namespace is needed as a suffix in almost all the commands, is it possible that I have my namespace as an alias. For e.g.

```
alias  myname=' -n mynamespace'
```

and then I use it in my command line

```
kubectl get pods 'myname'
```

In this way, I can create multiple aliases for different namespaces and just change the suffix at the end of my shell command.

Basically, all I want to do is to substitute the alias in my bash command and execute it.

UPDATE

I tried adding "`" symbol but it is not working

```
kubectl get pods `myname`

-n: command not found
No resources found in default namespace.
```

Comment: `alias` doesn't accept arguments. You need to create a [function](https://ss64.com/bash/function.html) and alias that. See [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/080)

Comment: True. But, I dont want alias to accept argument. for e.g alias myname = ' -n $1' This is not what I want. I just want to substitute the alias in the shell command before executing.

Comment: Why does it _have_ to be an alias? Maybe you're using the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Aliases are only expanded in command position. `myname` is not in command position here, so it is not subject to alias expansion. With backticks, it is, but the result of alias expansion does not produce a valid command name.

Comment: For comparison, `zsh` does allow "global" aliases which can be expanded in any position, but then you have to worry about regular arguments expanding unexpectedly when they happen to match a defined alias. IMO, global aliases should be avoided.

Comment: Hi, take a look [here](https://github.com/vaniacer/kube-dialog)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a function like this:

```
function myname() {
  "$@" -n mynamespace
}
```

The `"$@"` means "insert all arguments here". The double-quotes ensures that they are word-split correctly. Then you'd invoke it using

```
myname kubectl get pods
```

Syntax is a bit different but the behavior is the same. You could probably work something else out if you really wanted to use the syntax you want, but it would be more complicated.

Probably simpler would be to define a variable like this:

```
export myname="-n mynamespace"
```

and execute it using

```
kubectl get pods $myname
```

Comment: Thanks @eewanco. I used export to variable. This is the closest thing which I can do and it works pretty much the same way I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Use a variable instead of an alias.

```
myname='-n mynamespace'
kubectl get pods $myname
```

Comment: Thank you. eewanco had suggested the same thing. Thanks for te reply.

Answer (score 2):

Just store the data in an array.

```
myname=(-n mynamespace)

kubectl get pods "${myname[@]}"
```